# How to remove some special chracters from string?

Tags: java, string

I have below string

```
String str = "Test & 123 - Formula Nº 2";
```

When I am sending email via Mandrill API, then `Nº` this special character only cause after N.

Is there any common function or I will replace 1 by 1 from the string using regular expression?

I already have this solution

```
String result = str.replaceAll("[º]", "");
```

Is there better solution?

Comment: `str.replace("Nº", "N")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `java.text.Normalizer` should be good for this use case and others, at least you have a standard solution and do not need to handle and maintain regular expressions

```java
String str = "Test & 123 - Formula Nº 2";
System.out.println("Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD) = " + Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD));
```

Prints

```
Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD) = Test & 123 - Formula No 2
```

[Demo](https://www.ideone.com/09VG51)

Comment: It works Sir. But question why we use `NFKD`? Among NFD, NFC, NFKD, NFKC. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jackson, this is because `NFKD` offers us the compatibility we need for your use case. You could have also used `NKFC` which does an extra step of `canonical composition`. I'm not an expert in those matters but I hope I could shed some light already